# Streamplot in a longitudinal section with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinate

I have a spherical shell simulation and would like to plot a longitudinal slice like below showing the streamlines.

Meridional section with streamlines

[image]

The dashed and solid lines shown here have been plotted with matplotlib using the contours of the streamfunction obtained from the radial and angular velocities, `vr` and `vtheta`. However, I would like to achieve the same using streamplot. Could someone guide me towards how this would be possible?

Thanks!

If you need further information or code snippets, do ask.